# How to detect language of user entered text?

Tags: java, nlp, language-detection

I am dealing with an application that is accepting user input in different languages (currently 3 languages fixed). The requirement is that users can enter text and dont bother to select the language via a provided checkbox in the UI.

Is there an **existing Java library** to detect the language of a text?

I want something like this:

```
text = "To be or not to be thats the question."

// returns ISO 639 Alpha-2 code
language = detect(text);

print(language);
```

result:

```
EN
```

**I dont want to know how to create a language detector by myself** (i have seen plenty of blogs trying to do that). The library should provide a simple APi and also work completely offline. Open-source or commercial closed doesn't matter.

i also found this questions on SO (and a few more):

[How to detect language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173005)
[How to detect language of text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752691)

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383503/how-to-determine-the-natural-language-of-a-document

Comment: @S.Lott: thanks, i already read a lot, just searching for a working lib that works offline, dont want to create anything by myself.

Comment: Reliably recognizing natural language is considered a difficult problem. Any solution that fits in your code space and hard disk is not likely to be very good.

Comment: @Carl: it doesnt have to be 100% perfect. i am searching for "a good enough" but already implemented and maintained lib. if it works in 80% of all cases it's well enough for me.

Comment: Updated my answer to offer Guess-Language.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I tell what language is  a plain-text file written in ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326063/how-do-i-tell-what-language-is-a-plain-text-file-written-in)

Comment: This question is also closely related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464362/detect-language-of-text http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752691/how-to-detect-language-of-text http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161290/language-detection-in-python-closed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024934/is-there-a-python-library-class-that-can-take-a-piece-of-text-and-determine-the-l http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257125/human-language-of-a-document

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here are two options

- [LanguageIdentifier](http://www.lextek.com/langid/li/)
- [Rosette Language Identifier](http://www.basistech.com/language-identification/)

Answer (score 33):

This [Language Detection Library for Java](https://code.google.com/p/language-detection/) should give more than 99% accuracy for 53 languages.

Alternatively, there is [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/1.5/detection.html#Language_Detection), a library for content analysis that offers much more than just language detection.

Answer (score 6):

Google offers an API that can do this for you. I just stumbled across this yesterday and didn't keep a link, but if you, umm, Google for it you should manage to find it.

This was somewhere near the description of their translation API, which will translate text for you into any language you like. There's another call just for guessing the input language.

Google is among the world's leaders in mechanical translation; they base their stuff on extremely large corpuses of text (most of the Internet, kinda) and a statistical approach that usually "gets" it right simply by virtue of having a huge sample space.

EDIT: Here's the link: http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/

EDIT 2: If you insist on "offline": A well upvoted answer was the suggestion of [Guess-Language](http://code.google.com/p/guess-language/). It's a C++ library and handles about 60 languages.

Comment: this? -> http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/#Detect

Comment: @ManBugra: Only if you have a backup copy of Google's data storage facility handy ;)

Comment: @potatopeelings: I just dove into Google and found the very same thing. I'll update my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @potatopeelings: i have to admit my mother language isn't english but when i mention "offline" i mean it should work without any network connection (=no internet).

Comment: Guess-Language is python, so Jython should be able to run it from Java.

Comment: @tulskiy Oops, I was misled by the sentence "based on guesslanguage.cpp". Yep, good hint. Python and Java are not a match made in heaven, but they can be duct-taped together as you say.

Comment: @ManBugra - sorry, my fault. i probably read offline but it didn't register. i think your usage is right btw.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is the [JLangDetect](https://github.com/melix/jlangdetect) but it's not very robust and has a limited language base.  Good thing is it's an Apache license, if it satisfies your requirements, you can use it.  I'm guessing here, but do you release the space key between the single and double jump event?

In version 0.4 it is very robust. I have been using this in many projects of my own and never had any major problems. Also, when it comes to speed it is comparable to very specialized language detectors (e.g., few languages only).

Comment: There is version 0.3 release now and it detects even bulgarian.

Comment: Pardon, version 0.4 is available.

Answer (score 1):

[Detect Language API](http://detectlanguage.com) also provides [Java client](https://github.com/detectlanguage/detectlanguage-java).

Example:

```java
List<Result> results = DetectLanguage.detect("Hello world");

Result result = results.get(0);

System.out.println("Language: " + result.language);
System.out.println("Is reliable: " + result.reliable);
System.out.println("Confidence: " + result.confidence);
```

Comment: This method requires internet connection, this must be considered before using it on your app.

Answer (score 0):

here is another option : [Language Detection Library for Java](https://code.google.com/p/language-detection/)

this is a library in Java.

Answer (score 0):

```
Just a working code from already available solution from cybozu labs:

package com.et.generate;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.cybozu.labs.langdetect.Detector;
import com.cybozu.labs.langdetect.DetectorFactory;
import com.cybozu.labs.langdetect.LangDetectException;
import com.cybozu.labs.langdetect.Language;

public class LanguageCodeDetection {

    public void init(String profileDirectory) throws LangDetectException {
        DetectorFactory.loadProfile(profileDirectory);
    }
    public String detect(String text) throws LangDetectException {
        Detector detector = DetectorFactory.create();
        detector.append(text);
        return detector.detect();
    }
    public ArrayList<Language> detectLangs(String text) throws LangDetectException {
        Detector detector = DetectorFactory.create();
        detector.append(text);
        return detector.getProbabilities();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            LanguageCodeDetection ld = new  LanguageCodeDetection();

            String profileDirectory = "C:/profiles/";
            ld.init(profileDirectory);
            String text = "Кремль россий";
            System.out.println(ld.detectLangs(text));
            System.out.println(ld.detect(text));
        } catch (LangDetectException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

Output:
[ru:0.9999983255911719]
ru
```

Profiles can be downloaded from:
https://language-detection.googlecode.com/files/langdetect-09-13-2011.zip