# is there any library that assert text is in English?

Tags: java, android, localization

I want to build a form for the user to fill and submit.

There is a free text field.

How can i check the user didn't enter garbage, like: 
`fhskdjfhjkdshfkjhsd`

maybe like checking 3 random words are in English dictionary

or any other language i choose to check (Hebrew for the moment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could check out this library

https://code.google.com/p/language-detection/

or the ones mentioned in the answer to this question:

[How to detect language of user entered text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227524/how-to-detect-language-of-user-entered-text)