# how to extract only English HashTag from tweettext

Tags: java, twitter4j

I am using twitter streaming API to get real time tweets and I am checking lang . I am extracting hashTags from those tweets but the problem is when I am extracting the hashtags from tweettext iam getting english and non-english hashtags. Is there any way to extract only english hashtag from a particular tweettext.My code after getting tweettext to extract hashtags

```
private String getHashTag(String TweetText) {
     String[] words = TweetText.split(" ");
        Set<String> hashtags = new HashSet<String>();
        for (String word : words) {
            if (word.startsWith("#")) {
                hashtags.add(word);
            }
        }
        return hashtags.toString();
}
```

Comment: Define "English". You `[a-zA-Z]` characters or actual words that has meaning in English?

Comment: @MarounMaroun thanks I'll try this ... it sounds simple way

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/) and its API for language detection. This is an example:

```
import org.apache.tika.language.LanguageIdentifier;

LanguageIdentifier identifier = new LanguageIdentifier(word);
String language = identifier.getLanguage();
```

With this solution you can get the language and therefore consider only english tweets.

Comment: But I think if we are using the Apache Tika API we will face performance issue if I'm not wrong!!

Comment: Language detection is not a lightweight task! I think that if your data set is not too massive this solution could be ok! However your could directly mines your tweets selecting only English ones.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to detect the language of a string. See this post: [How to detect language of user entered text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227524/how-to-detect-language-of-user-entered-text)