# Detecting language of string value from a database column

Tags: java, database, language-detection

I have a school project idea and would like to ask for your advice on how to implement it.

I would like to create an application which will enable users to upload a data file. The application should be able to detect the language (french, english, etc) of a text field and populate the language column with the value. I can initially only implement a few languages, and the application should maybe give the probability of the language in the language column. E.g. 70% french 30% latin.

The questions in my mind area:
Can I implement those language rules myself into my application?
What is the ideal programming language the application should be written in? Java or C++?
I would appreciate any suggestions you might have. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could search for free dictionaries of the different languages. Then you can look up all the words of the text fields in the dictionaries. The more matches you get, the more likely is the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try the this link https://code.google.com/archive/p/language-detection/.

Also, there are already similar question are present check this [How to detect language of user entered text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227524/how-to-detect-language-of-user-entered-text)

Comment: thank you, how would the application be able to update the csv file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java and make use of [Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html)

Comment: thank you, how would the application be able to update the csv file?

Answer (score 0):

Use the link Narendra gave you. Google often has very good resources for these types of things.

Creating a language detector on your own would be a much harder endeavor in any case because you need many databases of languages and their dictionaries.

There's also the problem that you might come across similarities in languages that would inevitably make it harder to sort these types of problems out. But then again, programming is problem solving... go for it!