# Web page Language detection based on content

Tags: java, language-detection

I am working on web page language detection and I managed to retrieve the content of a page through other middleware I developed. since there is no standardization the content location. However, I don't know how to detect the language I tried to use lang and xml:lang tag but they are not efficient as I expected it because I have seen some website has a different language other than what specified in the tag,any help will be appreciated? (environment java eclipse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classical problem in nlp, and gives pretty good predictions. This post looks similar to this one: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227524/how-to-detect-language-of-user-entered-text) and have there some good answers.
I'm not familiar with the solutions mentioned there, but I did used the Apache Tika for another matter and it's a great open source. Hope that helps..

Comment: I am working on java and I already check the link but the library they referred (specifically language detector)has some issue of accuracy it gives different result for the same text and supports limited language