# How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in the following code?

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, language-detection

I am new to NLP and JAVA. Recently I started working on language detection and 
i got a code from [How to detect language of user entered text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227524/how-to-detect-language-of-user-entered-text). I am using NetBeans 8.2 and copied the following code in it:

```
package landslip_langdetect;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.cybozu.labs.langdetect.Detector;
import com.cybozu.labs.langdetect.DetectorFactory;
import com.cybozu.labs.langdetect.LangDetectException;
import com.cybozu.labs.langdetect.Language;

public class LanguageCodeDetection {
    public void init(String profileDirectory) throws LangDetectException {
        DetectorFactory.loadProfile(profileDirectory);
}

public String detect(String text) throws LangDetectException {
    Detector detector = DetectorFactory.create();
    detector.append(text);
    return detector.detect();
}

public ArrayList<Language> detectLangs(String text) throws LangDetectException {
    Detector detector = DetectorFactory.create();
    detector.append(text);
    return detector.getProbabilities();
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        LanguageCodeDetection ld = new LanguageCodeDetection();
        String profileDirectory = "C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\LangDetect\\profiles\\";
        ld.init(profileDirectory);
        String text = "Кремль россий";
        System.out.println(ld.detectLangs(text));
        System.out.println(ld.detect(text));
    } catch (LangDetectException e) {
    }
}
```

}

"profiles" folder, I just download from github(https://github.com/shuyo/language-detection) and simply given the path in  "profileDirectory"

I am getting the error as:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/arnx/jsonic/JSONException
at shyjo_langDetect.LanguageCodeDetection_1.init(LanguageCodeDetection_1.java:21)
at shyjo_langDetect.LanguageCodeDetection_1.main(LanguageCodeDetection_1.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.arnx.jsonic.JSONException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more

C:\Users\geethu\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I added the required jar file into the library also(http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/l/Downloadlangdetectjar.htm)
Since I am new to JAVA, I couldn't understand why this error is coming. Can anyone help me to resolve the error and make the code working?

Comment: have u added net.arnx.jsonic jar in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add the **jsonic-1.2.0.jar** and **langdetect.jar** into the Build path of your NetBeans project. You can find both these Jar's under the **lib** directory of the GitHub URL which you had provided earlier.

Post change, you should be able to get the desired output:

```
[ru:0.9999987658571312]
ru
```