# How do we know whether or not a word in English? .NET Ranorex C#

Tags: .net, text, localization, ranorex

I try to test a UI In Ranorex. I want to check  to In homepage all the text is English.

But I dont know it. How do we know whether or not a word in English? by Google apı or .NET

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine the (natural) language of a document?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383503/how-to-determine-the-natural-language-of-a-document)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check it with using regular expression i.e. `^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$` in following way:

```
if( Regex.IsMatch("yourWord", "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$") )
{
    ///Put the code here when word is english
}
```

Comment: But
I want to make the distinction, for example english french

Comment: For that, you have to make more advanced regular expression by using possible characters used in particular language.....